# GeForce 8600GT error C5060: out can't be used with non-varying color

Tags: opengl, glsl

Is anyone know why for shaders like...

Vertex.shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 vertexNormal;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 vertexTexcoord;

out vec3 gouraud;
out vec2 texcoord;

uniform mat4 pMatrix; // projection matrix
uniform mat4 vMatrix; // view matrix
uniform mat4 mMatrix; // model matrix
uniform mat3 nMatrix; // mMatrix -> inverted and transposed

#define NUM_LIGHTS 32
struct Light {

    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
    vec4 position; // w == 0 -> directional
    vec4 attenuation;

};
uniform Light lights[NUM_LIGHTS];

struct Material {

    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
    float shininess;

};
uniform Material material;

void main() {

    vec4 position = vec4(vertexPosition, 1.0);

    vec3 vertex = vec3(mMatrix * position); // vertex in model space
    vec3 normal = normalize(nMatrix * vertexNormal); // normal in model space

    vec3 finalColor = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0); // phong result

    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_LIGHTS; ++i) {

        if(lights[i].position.w == 0.0) { // directional light

            vec3 lightDirection = normalize(lights[i].position.xyz);

            vec3 N = normalize(normal); // normalize because normal will be interpolated (possible not unit vector)
            vec3 E = normalize(-vertex);
            vec3 R = normalize(-reflect(lightDirection, N));

            finalColor += lights[i].ambient; // * material.ambient; // ambient

            float lambert = max(dot(N, lightDirection), 0.0);

            if(lambert > 0.0) {

                finalColor += lights[i].diffuse * material.diffuse * lambert; // diffuse

                float specular = pow(max(0.0, dot(reflect(-lightDirection, N), E)), material.shininess);
                finalColor += lights[i].specular * material.specular * clamp(specular, 0.0, 1.0); // specular

            }

        }
        else { // point light

            vec3 lightDirection = lights[i].position.xyz - vertex;

            float lightDistance = length(lightDirection);

            lightDirection = normalize(lightDirection);

            float attenuation = 1.0;
            if(lights[i].attenuation[0] != 0.0) { // attenuation based on light radius

                attenuation = smoothstep(lights[i].attenuation[0], 0.0, lightDistance);

            }
            else { // attenuation based on distance

                attenuation = clamp(1.0 /
                                   (lights[i].attenuation[1]                 +
                                    lights[i].attenuation[2] * lightDistance +
                                    lights[i].attenuation[3] * pow(lightDistance, 2)), 0.0, 1.0);

            }

            finalColor += lights[i].ambient * material.ambient;

            vec3 N = normalize(normal); // normalize because normal will be interpolated (possible not unit vector)
            float lambert = max(dot(N, lightDirection), 0.0);

            if(lambert > 0.0) {

                finalColor += lights[i].diffuse * material.diffuse * lambert * attenuation; // diffuse

                vec3 E = normalize(-vertex);
                vec3 R = normalize(-reflect(lightDirection, N));

                float specular = pow(max(0.0, dot(reflect(-lightDirection, N), E)), material.shininess);
                finalColor += lights[i].specular * material.specular * clamp(specular, 0.0, 1.0) * attenuation; // specular

            }

        }

    }

    gouraud = finalColor;
    texcoord = vertexTexcoord;

    gl_Position = pMatrix * vMatrix * mMatrix * position;

}
```

Fragment.shader:

```
#version 330 core

in vec3 gouraud;
in vec2 texcoord;

out vec3 color;

uniform sampler2D diffuseMap;

void main() {

    color = gouraud * texture(diffuseMap, texcoord).rgb;

}
```

Runned on nVidia GeForce 8600GT and nVidia 710m the result is?

> error C5060: out can't be used with non-varying color

But it's running on intel hd 2500..

**Problem is only with nVidia.**

Help :<

**Update: full shader**

Comment: Do you by any chance have a uniform in the `...` of your vertex shader named "color"? :) I guess what I'm asking for is the full shader. Nothing else looks out of the ordinary.

Comment: I updated shader :) Waiting for yours response ^^

Comment: Did you try with an explicit output location? `layout(location = 0) out vec3 color;`

Comment: with explicit output location i'm getting "error C0000: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting "::" at token "("", with/without explicit is working under intel, ATI card hasn't got any problems with shaders too.

Comment: when i change "out vec3 color" to "varying out vec3 color" it's working under nvidia, but under intel and ati doesn't. ?!

Comment: That should generate a parse error in GLSL 330. Chances are pretty good that your GT 8600 driver does not support OpenGL 3.3. The hardware itself can implement most of OpenGL 3.3 and newer drivers will give you OpenGL 3.3, but if the driver is out of date then this would explain a lot.

Comment: Yes i know it, but nVidia 710m support OpenGL 4.3 and result is the same ;/

Comment: What driver version do you have on the 710m? What happens if you remove `core` from the version string? Maybe try others such as 150 or 430? Is it the same with `out vec4`?